# Tipp/Stopp im Deutschen, aber Tip/Stop im Englischen?

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context, spelling

Wenn man nach den oben gennaten Wörtern sucht, überschlagen sich die Suchergebnisse, also frage ich einfach mal direkt.

Seit der neuen Rechtschreibung hat sich das Wort Tip**p** mit zwei 'p' im Duden fest verankert. Das gilt für den Tipp im Sinne von Hinweis oder Ratschlag.

Wenn ich aber jetzt das amerikanische Wort für Trinkgeld nehme, dann würde ich dieses Wort weiterhin Tip schreiben.

Bei dem Wort Stop in der wörtlichten Rede bin ich mir dagegen nicht so sicher. Auf Verkehrsschildern werde ich aufgefordert, anzuhalten, genau wie im Englischen mit einem 'p', in der wörtlichen Rede wird es aber mit **Stopp** geschrieben - laut Duden. Das ist mir insofern nicht klar, als dass ich das Wort "Stopp" als Substantiv für die Tätigkeit stoppen sehe, die Aufforderung dazu aber mit der Botschaft auf dem Schild gleichsetzen würde.

Deswegen erscheint mit die Schreibweise "Start-Stop-System" genauso verkehrt, weil es sich nicht um eine Aufforderung handelt - jedoch andererseits ist dieses Wort auch englischen Ursprungs und würde daher mit einem 'p' genauso plausibel erscheinen.

Was übersehe ich hier? Und wann schreibe ich die beiden nun mit zwei 'p' im Deutschen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter werden jeweils mit Doppel-p geschrieben, siehe Duden. Durch den kurzen Vokal ist die Schreibweise nach der neuen Rechtschreibung ebenfalls eindeutig. Das Verkehrszeichen wird international verwendet, weswegen dessen Beschriftung englisch und nicht deutsch ist. Das Wort *Tip* für Trinkgeld gibt es so im Deutschen nicht. Du gibst dem Kellner ein Trinkgeld und keinen *Tip*. *Tip* verwenden höchstens schlecht synchronisierte Filme oder Personen, die ihren letzten USA-Urlaub heraushängen lassen wollen. ;)

Die englischen Wörter *Stop* und *Tip* können auch im Deutschen in englischen Wortkombinationen vorkommen. Das *Start-Stop-System* sollte also eher englisch anstatt deutsch ausgesprochen werden. *Start-Stop-System* ist aber ein ungünstiges Beispiel, weil es alle Wörter auch im Deutschen gibt. Wenn ich aber im *Stop-And-Go-Verkehr* festhänge, ist die Herkunft von *Stop* aus dem Englischen klarer.

Weil es beide Wörter sowohl im Englischen als auch im Deutschen aber mit der etwas unterschiedlichen Schreibweise gibt, findest du wahrscheinlich auch sehr viele Beispiele für die falsche Verwendung im Deutschen. Das ist analog zur falschen Getrennt- (z. B. *Schoko Kuchen*) und Genitivschreibung (z.B. *Bernie's Imbiss*).

Comment: Klasse, das Beispiel mit dem Stop-and-Go. Das ist viel klarer als meins. Das Wort Tip findet sich schon auf Kreditkartenabrechnungen wieder - auch bei uns in Deutschland. Aber es ist klargeworden, wie ich in Zukunft schreiben muss, danke dafür.